# Back button in web application

Tags: asp.net

I have web application contain more than one page.
I need to guarantee when I click Back in browser it execute the page-load event because in last page when I click bake it bring the previous page but it doesn’t execute page load and that cause problems.
I appreciate any help

Answer (score 3):

When using the back button the browser displays a cached version of your page. It does not send a new request to your server.  This is why your Page_Load is not firing.

You may want to take a look at [HttpCachePolicy.SetCacheability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4yy9w70.aspx) that allows you to control caching.

Comment: I add this Line 
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
and tha back works correctly between pages but when I raise event in the same page and then click back it give me message " expired web page"

Comment: You will get the "expired web page" because the browser cannot do a HTTP POST when pressing back.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to ensure the page is not cached in the brower.

An HTTP header such as

```
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
```

should achieve that.

Although different web browsers may implement this differently, and it is possible a user's settings may override the HTTP header directives.

(This is speculation, I have not tested this)

Coding your app in such a way as to not rely on the page load event would be much better.